# Spring Data Neo4j 4 and dynamic product properties

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my Neo4j/SDN project I have to implement a following task - I have a parent Node(let's say `ParentNode`) that must define a set of product characteristics, for example:

```
weight: Double
size: Integer
license: String
active: Boolean
```

Also, new product characteristics(**with any new name and type**) can be added during the application runtime.

`ParentNode` can have a set of child nodes(let's say `ProductNode`) and each of these nodes can provide an own value for a certain characteristic defined by a `ParentNode`.

Based on these characteristics names and values I need to have possibility to filter a `ProductNode` nodes.

Previously this structure have been implemented by me by SDN3 DynamicProperties but AFAIK - DynamicProperties support has been removed from SDN 4.

So my question is - how to implement the following structure based on SDN 4 ?

**UPDATED**

Also, how about the idea to define every `ParentNode` characteristic as a separate node(let's say `CharacteristicNode`)

for example

```
CharacteristicNode.name = weight
CharacteristicNode.type = Double

CharacteristicNode.name = license
CharacteristicNode.type = String

...
```

and every `ProductNode` can provide a value node(`CharacteristicValueNode`) associated with `ProductNode`  and  `CharacteristicNode`.

The main question here how to support different types for `CharacteristicValueNode` and how to filter `ProductNode` nodes based on different characteristic and their values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SDN 4, you can model these properties as a Map of (property name, value) and write a [custom converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_conversion-custom). This will convert the Map to a String property on the node (json style perhaps), and then from the graph back to your Map.

The downside to this is that it is not easy to write a custom query for these dynamic properties because they're not really stored in the graph as independent properties- rather, your converter will squash them into a single one.

**Update**

If you were to define each `Characteristic` type as a node (in your example, you would have 4 nodes- one representing each of weight,size,active,license), then you don't need an intermediate `CharacteristicValueNode` to relate the `ProductNode` and the `CharacteristicNode`. Instead, you can model the value of the produce for the characteristic on the relationship between the `ProductNode` and `CharacteristicNode`.
For example, if the `ProductNode` had only weight and size, then you would have two relationships- one from `ProductNode` to the weight `CharacteristicNode` with the weight value on the relationship, and another from the ProductNode to the size `CharacteristicNode` with the size value on that relationship.

In SDN 4, these would be modelled as RelationshipEntities. For example,

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="CHARACTERISTIC")
public class ProductCharacteristic {

Long id;
@StartNode ProductNode product;
@EndNode CharacteristicNode characteristic;
int value;
...

}
```

The ProductNode would contain a collection of these relationship entities

```
Set<ProductCharacteristic> characteristics;
```

Then you can query for products related to characteristics with a certain name. Or query for `ProductCharacteristic` with `findByCharacteristicName`

I haven't really tried this approach out, but it is worth thinking about the change that this forces in your underlying graph model to support dynamic properties.

Comment: Great idea, thanks ! One more question, how to filter the nodes based on a properties inside of this JSON ?

Comment: That's the downside mentioned in the answer- you would not be able to use derived queries or filters. You'd have to write a cypher query yourself to do this with some property value string parsing and this may be quite hard to do :(

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also comment the idea described in my updated question? Does it make sense ?

Comment: Thanks! The biggest question right now is how to deal with different types(String, Integer, Boolean and so on) for values