# Neo4j Cypher query with multiple conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my SDN 4 project I have a following entitites:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Characteristic extends Authorable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;

}

@NodeEntity
public class Decision extends Commentable {

    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Characteristic> characteristics = new HashSet<>();

}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC")
public class DecisionCharacteristic {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Decision decision;

    @EndNode
    private Characteristic characteristic;

    private Object value;

}
```

I need to select a `Decision` nodes that match the specific characteristics.

I have created a following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} MATCH (childD)-[rdc:DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC]->(characteristic:Characteristic) WHERE  ( ( (  id(characteristic) = 138 AND  (rdc.value > 15000.32)) AND (  id(characteristic) = 138 AND  (rdc.value < 50000.32)) ) AND (  id(characteristic) = 139 AND  (rdc.value = 'Commercial')) )  WITH childD, ru, u RETURN childD
```

but this query works wrong. I need to select a Decision nodes that for characteristic with `id=138` has a `value between 15000.32 and 50000.32` and for characteristic with `id=139` has exact `value = 'Commercial'`.

Where I'm wrong in my query and how to transform it in order to get working as expected ?

**UPDATED**

I have a following nodes:

```
        DecisionCharacteristic neo4jPriceDecisionCharacteristic = new DecisionCharacteristic(neo4jDecision, priceCharacteristic, new Double(10000.32d));
        decisionCharacteristicRepository.save(neo4jPriceDecisionCharacteristic);

        DecisionCharacteristic oraclePriceDecisionCharacteristic = new DecisionCharacteristic(oracleDecision, priceCharacteristic, new Double(35000.2d));
        decisionCharacteristicRepository.save(oraclePriceDecisionCharacteristic);

        assertNotNull(neo4jPriceDecisionCharacteristic);
        assertNotNull(neo4jPriceDecisionCharacteristic.getId());

        DecisionCharacteristic neo4jLicenseDecisionCharacteristic = new DecisionCharacteristic(neo4jDecision, licenseCharacteristic, "Commercial");
        decisionCharacteristicRepository.save(neo4jLicenseDecisionCharacteristic);

        DecisionCharacteristic orientLicenseDecisionCharacteristic = new DecisionCharacteristic(orientDecision, licenseCharacteristic, "Free");
        decisionCharacteristicRepository.save(orientLicenseDecisionCharacteristic);

        DecisionCharacteristic oracleLicenseDecisionCharacteristic = new DecisionCharacteristic(oracleDecision, licenseCharacteristic, "Commercial");
        decisionCharacteristicRepository.save(oracleLicenseDecisionCharacteristic);
```

IDs:

```
priceCharacteristic ID: 138
licenseCharacteristic ID: 139
```

I'm trying to get a `Decision` nodes with a following query:

```
   MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} MATCH (childD)-[rdc:DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC]->(characteristic:Characteristic) WHERE  ( id(characteristic) = 138 AND  ( id(characteristic) = 138 AND  (  (rdc.value > 15000.32)) AND (  (rdc.value < 50000.32)) ) OR (  id(characteristic) = 139 AND  (rdc.value = 'Commercial')) )  RETURN childD
```

I expect that only `oracleDecision` node matches this condition but it returns two nodes:

```
Neo4j
Oracle
```

Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Can you add to your description the ids of each of the characteristics? You're matching on 138 or 139, but we can't tell which ones those refer to.

Comment: I have updated my question: priceCharacteristic ID: 138
licenseCharacteristic ID: 139

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main flaw in your query is using ANDs to create an impossible where clause. You are literally asking it to return values where the id is two different numbers, and where the rdc.value is multiple values simultaneously...impossible. You need to use ORs instead in the right places so you can match on one id OR another id. Also, we can improve on the rdc.value restriction.

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
MATCH (childD)-[rdc:DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC]->(characteristic:Characteristic) 
WHERE  (id(characteristic) = 138 AND (15000.32 < rdc.value < 50000.32)) 
OR (id(characteristic) = 139 AND (rdc.value = 'Commercial'))  
WITH childD, ru, u 
RETURN childD
```

Lastly you don't need the WITH clause at all since you're only returning childD. Unsure if that's because you forgot to return the other variables in the return, but if you're truly only returning childD, then you can eliminate your WITH clause, as well as the ru and u variables in your first line match. If :Decisions are always created by users, then you can trim your first match by getting rid of "-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)". This would make your query look like:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
MATCH (childD)-[rdc:DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC]->(characteristic:Characteristic) 
WHERE  (id(characteristic) = 138 AND (15000.32 < rdc.value < 50000.32)) 
OR (id(characteristic) = 139 AND (rdc.value = 'Commercial'))  
RETURN childD
```

EDIT

Ah, okay, it wasn't clear from your query that you want to match on two different types of characteristics and place restrictions on both. In that case a single match against a characteristic will not be enough. You'll need to specify them separately.

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[:CREATED_BY]->(:User)
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
MATCH (childD)-[pdc:DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC]->(priceChar:Characteristic) 
WHERE  (id(priceChar) = 138 AND (15000.32 < pdc.value < 50000.32))
MATCH (childD)-[ldc:DECISION_CHARACTERISTIC]->(licenseChar:Characteristic) 
WHERE (id(licenseChar) = 139 AND (ldc.value = 'Commercial'))  
RETURN childD
```

I've got to ask, are you really okay with modeling your graph this way? You have Characteristic nodes, but you're storing characteristic data on relationships instead of the nodes themselves. You're also using a single Characteristic node when it seems clear that you actually have separate types, like PriceCharacteristic and LicenseCharacteristic and others. Do you have requirements or good reasons to do this, or do you have freedom to make changes to how your graph data is represented?

Comment: Thanks ! I have updated my question. The query still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Updated my answer to work with your clarified requirements.

Comment: Thanks ! Please see another my question for a reason of this scheme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639178/spring-data-neo4j-4-and-dynamic-product-properties

Comment: One last thing to note...in your queries, it's generally not a good idea to use the neo4j ids in your query, as the ids can be reused and there may be some things that can happen that can change them (maybe when setting up clustering or replicating data). It's better practice to set your own ID property based on an externally generated unique ID, and place unique and existence constraints on that ID field for the given label(s).

Comment: Hmm. After looking at that other question, I'm still doubtful about how this is modeled. Storing the value of the characteristic on the relationship to the characteristic rather than the characteristic itself seems like a mistake to me. Seems like it would be better to have each characteristic as its own label type (LicenseCharacteristic, PriceCharacteristic) and create separate nodes off of each product for each one, setting the values in those nodes accordingly. That is, if you aren't able to simply model these as properties on your product nodes instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me what is a potential drawback with my current implementation ? The main criteria to me is a performance. If the current schema will perform fast - then I'm fully satisfied with this.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be an issue either way. And the current design isn't really a drawback per se, unless you want to query starting from a certain characteristic, in which case the queries become awkward because the value fields you care about are on the relationships from characteristics, not the characteristics themselves. It's more of a design smell...it works, but the modeling just feels off, and with more experience with neo4j and writing queries against this model, that may become clearer. You also can't apply indexes to relationship properties, or unique constraints if needed.